# Added text in pdf not displayed in browser using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I've added text in pdf. But the added text is not displayed in browser.

```
  using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(highLightFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
            {
                for (int x = 1; x < reader.NumberOfPages; x++)
                {
                    cb = stamper.GetUnderContent(x);
                    myLocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new myLocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                    strategy.UndercontentCharacterSpacing = cb.CharacterSpacing;
                    strategy.UndercontentHorizontalScaling = cb.HorizontalScaling;
                    string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, x, strategy);
                    foreach (iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect in MatchesFound)
                    {
                         //----------Annotation ----------------
                         iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect_txt = rect;
                         BaseFont helv = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                         rect_txt.Bottom = rect_txt.Top - 2;
                         rect_txt.Top = rect_txt.Top + 8;
                         rect_txt.Right = rect_txt.Right - ((rect_txt.Width) - Convert.ToInt32(text_num.ToString().Length) * 5);
                         rect_txt.Left = rect_txt.Left - 3.0f;
                         PdfAnnotation comment = PdfAnnotation.CreateFreeText(stamper.Writer, rect_txt, text_num.ToString(), cb);
                         comment.PlaceInPage = x;
                         comment.Put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:xfa=\"http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/\" xfa:APIVersion=\"Acrobat:11.0.13\" xfa:spec=\"2.0.2\" style=\"font-size:9.0pt;text-align:left;color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;font-family:'helvetica';font-stretch:normal\"><p dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-family:helvetica\">" + text_num.ToString() + "</span></p></body>", PdfObject.TEXT_UNICODE));
                         comment.BorderStyle = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfBorderDictionary(0, 0);
     stamper.AddAnnotation(comment, x); 
                    }
                }
           }
      }
```

Comment: Find out the answer.  appearance = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(stamper.Writer, rect_txt.Width, rect_txt.Height);
                                        appearance.Rectangle(0, 0, rect_txt.Width, rect_txt.Height);
                                        appearance.SetFontAndSize(helv, 12);
                                        appearance.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
                                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(appearance, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(text_num), 0, 0, 0);

Comment: Please post that as an actual answer.to your question, not a mere comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//----------Annotation --------------

iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect_txt = rect;

rect_txt.Bottom = rect_txt.Top - 2;
rect_txt.Top = rect_txt.Top + 8;
rect_txt.Right = rect_txt.Right - ((rect_txt.Width) - Convert.ToInt32(text_num.ToString().Length) * 5);
rect_txt.Left = rect_txt.Left - 3.0f;

BaseFont helv = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
appearance = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(stamper.Writer, rect_txt.Width, rect_txt.Height);
appearance.Rectangle(0, 0, rect_txt.Width, rect_txt.Height);
appearance.SetFontAndSize(helv, 12);
appearance.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(appearance, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(text_num), 0, 0, 0);
//appearance.FillStroke(); 
//   appearance.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, text_num.ToString(), 0, 0, 0);

PdfAnnotation comment = PdfAnnotation.CreateFreeText(stamper.Writer, rect_txt, text_num.ToString(), cb);
comment.PlaceInPage = x;
comment.Put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:xfa=\"http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/\" xfa:APIVersion=\"Acrobat:11.0.13\" xfa:spec=\"2.0.2\" style=\"font-size:10px;text-align:left;color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;font-family:'helvetica';font-stretch:normal\"><p dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-family:helvetica\">" + text_num.ToString() + "</span></p></body>", PdfObject.TEXT_UNICODE));
comment.BorderStyle = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfBorderDictionary(0, 0);
comment.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, appearance);
stamper.AddAnnotation(comment, x);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and don't simply paste code from your IDE. The goal is that others may learn from your answer. Thank you!